# Adding Columns with Data in jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, double

I have a `JTable` and I'm using the `DefaultTableModel`. I have one row, but I'm trying to add many columns using a for loop because the table is created dynamically.

With `addColumn`, I understand the first argument should be a string for the column name, but how can I pass a double for the data value in the table? I have read the definitions (the use of object or vector) but I'm having no luck with them:

```
String colName = "ColName";
double value = 1.2;
model.addColumn(colName, new double[]{ value });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addColumn(Object columnName, Object[] columnData)` this method only accepting arrays of objects which are extending from `java.lang.Object`. So if you use `new Double[]{ value }` instead of `new double[]{ value }` it will work.